# Laptop LEDs replacement widget

Tags: laptop, led, widgets

I bought a new high-end customized laptop. Surprisingly it has no LEDs besides the power button. Specifically I'm missing the hard drive LED, WiFi LED and Bluetooth LED.

I'm looking for a nice replacement widget for these LEDs. Ideally it should be nested in the System Tray, but other options would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Keyboard :
[Keyboard Leds](http://www.karpolan.com/SOFTWARE/KEYBOARD-LEDS/), which does Caps, Num and Scroll lock indicator in the system tray.

For hard disk:
[DiskLED](http://www.sepago.de/helge/2009/10/19/diskled-a-flexible-hard-disk-and-general-system-activity-indicator-system-tray-applet/) - A Flexible Hard Disk and General System Activity Indicator System Tray Applet
[Hard Disk Indicator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Hard-Disk-Indicator.shtml) - can monitor 5 partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net).  It's a system monitoring tool that uses skins to display information collected by meters.

You could create a custom skin that will display a graphic when there is disk access, wifi connection, and a lot of other things.  If you're up to creating a custom skin, you can definitely collect and show that information.